# Oracle bind insert example needed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create a script that uses bind variables within oracle.

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/bind_variables.html provides the most info, but i cannot get the syntax correct.

```
insert into history_text (itemid,clock,ns,value) values (:1,:2,:3,:4)
102857,1568735807,994374837,'maint'
102884,1568735807,996865154,'dev'
64782,1568735808,64131520,'Linux'
468595,1568735808,90767673,'deployed'
468620,1568735808,98388037,'cat'
```

To create the table for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    itemid                   number(20)                                NOT NULL,
    clock                    number(10)      DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL,
    value                    nclob           DEFAULT ''                ,
    ns                       number(10)      DEFAULT '0'               NOT NULL
);
```

I would like a script that would be able to do a bulk insert with the values above. This is for my oracle DBA to be able to test insert performance on a database.

I want to do a bind variable insert because that is the way to mimic the software that I am using.

Comment: why do you what to use bind variables? why not just an insert into?

Comment: I want to do a bind variable insert because that is the way to mimic the software that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
begin
  for rec in (
              select 102857 as itemid,1568735807 as clock,994374837 as ns,'maint' as  value from dual union all
              select 102884,1568735807,996865154,'dev' as value from dual union all
              select 64782,1568735808,64131520,'Linux' as value from dual union all
              select 468595,1568735808,90767673,'deployed' as value from dual union all
              select 468620,1568735808,98388037,'cat' as value from dual)
  loop
     execute immediate 'insert into <table_name> (itemid,clock,ns,value) values (:1,:2,:3,:4)' 
       using rec.itemid,rec.clock,rec.ns,rec.value;
  end loop;
end;
/
```